# Trigger VSTS Build after docker hub image update

Tags: docker, azure-devops, dockerhub

I run a docker image for data processing on a windows server 2016 (single vm, On Premises). My image is stored in a Azure Container Registry. The code does not change often. To get security Updates I like to get a rebuild and release after the microsoft/windowsservercoreis updated.

Is there a Best Practice Way to do this?

I thought about 3 ways of solving this:

1. Run a scheduled build every 24h, pull the microsoft/windowsservercore, pull my custom image, run powershell to get the build dates and compare then (or use some of the histroy ids). If a rebuild is needed, build the new image and tag the build. Configure the Release to run only on this tag.
2. Run a Job to check the update time of the docker image and trigger the build with a REST request.
3. Put a basic Dockerfile on github. Set up automated Build with a trigger to microsoft/windowsservercore and configure the webhook to a WebService, which start the Build with REST.

But I really like non of these Ideas. Is there a better option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I choose option three. Therefore I set up a github [repository](https://github.com/StefanSchoof/windowsserverdocker) with a one line [Dockerfile](https://github.com/StefanSchoof/windowsserverdocker/blob/master/Dockerfile):

```
FROM alpine
```

I used the alpine image and not the windowsservercore, because automated build does currently does not support windows images. I configured a automated build in the docker hub and add a Linked Repositories to [microsoft/windowsservercore](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/windowsservercore/). 
[image: Linked Repositories to windowsservercore]
Then I set up a [MS Flow](https://flow.microsoft.com/) with a HTTP Request Trigger to start the Build. [image: Flow to start the build] Add the Flow URL to a new webhook on the automated build.

For me this are to many moving parts that has to configured and work together, but I know no better way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Azure Container Registry webhooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-webhook) directly, the simple workflow:

1. Build a Web Api project to queue build per to detail request (webhook request) through [Queue a build Rest API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#queue-a-build)
2. Create an Azure Container Registry webhook to call Web API (step1)

Comment: I want to run the build when the microsoft/windowsservercore docker hub image is updated. But the documentation of the acr webhook says "You use webhooks to trigger events when certain actions take place in **one of your registry repositories**".

Comment: Check this way [Configure automated builds on Docker Hub](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/). (Not clear the third way of yours, maybe they are similar)

Comment: Yes, this was my third idea.

Comment: @sschoof Scheduled build or job is OK too, seems not the best way.

Comment: I set up a automated Build and used MS Flow to trigger the build. See https://github.com/StefanSchoof/windowsserverdocker